# How can I perform this MySql Statement in a loop

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, common-table-expression, window-functions

I would write my cmd line statements more sophistically. How can this be done by using a loop?

```
     update refs set custom_7 = '';
     update refs set custom_7='1' where custom_7 = '' limit 220 ;
     update refs set custom_7='2' where custom_7 = '' limit 220 ;
     update refs set custom_7='3' where custom_7 = '' limit 220 ;
     ...
     update refs set custom_7='100' where custom_7 = '' limit 220 ;
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any column that can represent the order, otherwise`limit` makes no sence.

Comment: even with an order with out offset you will  update teh same values agaian and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a column, like an `id`, that defines the order of the rows by which you want to update the rows, use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank the rows and join to the table:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM refs)
UPDATE refs r
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.id = r.id
SET r.custom_7 = (c.rn - 1) DIV 220 + 1
WHERE c.rn <= 100 * 220; -- remove the WHERE clause if there is actually no limit to the values of custom_7
```

If there is no column like the `id`, you may remove `ORDER BY id` from the `OVER()` clause of `ROW_NUMBER()`, but then the rows will be updated arbitrarily.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8d114c3559c41c99b6d9e6e42091966).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (please replace **datatype(length)** with the type of custom7)

```
DECLARE @count INT;    
SET @count = 1;        
WHILE @count<= 100    
     BEGIN
   
          UPDATE refs SET custom_7 = CAST(@count AS **datatype(length)**) WHERE custom_7 = '' LIMIT 220;    
          SET @count = @count + 1;    
     END;
```

Comment: without   an order you will update the same values over and over again

Comment: I use MariaDB an get (after make `Declare @ count INT;` as comment ) this error: `[SQL]         
WHILE @count<= 100    
     BEGIN
          UPDATE refs SET custom_7 = CAST(@count AS mediumtext) WHERE custom_7 = '' LIMIT 220;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
          UPDATE refs SET custom_7 = CAST(@count AS mediumtext) WHERE cus' at line 2`

Comment: Assigning & reading the same variable in the same select statement is explicitly undefined behaviour.

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair MySQL<>MariaDB. Aslo see my last comment here.

Comment: @philipxy thanks that makes it clear. I thought I could use MySQL also for MariaDB